# Why I got this "A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save" at random frequencies?

Tags: c#, image, file, gdi+

Here's my basic code:

```
#region privateMethods
private bool SaveImageFile(string absolutePathFile, byte[] file, ImageFormat format)
{
    try
    {
        string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(absolutePathFile);
        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        if (File.Exists(absolutePathFile)) File.Delete(absolutePathFile);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file))
        using (var bmp = Image.FromStream(ms))     
            bmp.Save(absolutePathFile, format);

        return true;

    }
    catch (ArgumentException argEx)
    {
        EventLogger.WriteLog("UploadImageFile: This file it isn't an image " + argEx.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLogger.WriteLog("UploadImageFile: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + "PathFile: " + absolutePathFile, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems very basic. Which could be the cause? Or how can I investigate better?

It seems to happens not always, but "sometimes". That's really weird and under control, the randomness of the happening...

Comment: Are you sure the bitmaps are valid? Are you running any weird P/Invoke or `unsafe` code anywhere else in the app? Are you running this multi-threaded? Is the top of the stack trace `System.Drawing.Image.Save` and what is the actual exception type?

Comment: @Charlieface where do you see the "exception type"? Do you mean inner exception?

Comment: No, just the actual class of the exception. But looking at the source code, it will always be `ExternalException`, and the error comes directly from Win32 GDI+, it is not generated by  .Net It is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplustypes/ne-gdiplustypes-status) where it says "Indicates that there was an error on the method call, which is identified as something other than those defined by the other elements of this enumeration." Not very helpful. I suspect unsafe code going wrong somewhere else in the app, but who knows.

Comment: What is the `ImageFormat` set to here? Does it match the original file format (probably not, since you have a GDI+ exception)? Where does the byte array come from? Did you check the File Write rights in the destination path?

Comment: @Jimi I produce the same files, it just go error sometimes. It comes from web api. File Write are ok (since it works 99% of the time).

Comment: I don't know what *I produce the same files* means. You have a GDI+ *exception* there. 1. The Codec cannot decode/encode the byte array to a know Bitmap. 2. The *internal* image format doesn't match the `ImageFormat` you have specified (otherwise the byte array would have been saved using a FileStream and not GDI+) and the `ImageFormat` specified cannot generate a Bitmap (e.g., Metafile) 3. The image bytes don't represent an Image or the array is partial or null 4. You cannot write to the path specified while redefining a valid format. 5. Invalid path. A couple of other less common reasons.